# Generic Querying using Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm working on an application that uses a generic Slick class to make queries based on information (such as url, user, pass, column count, etc) provided in metadata files or property files. As a result, I am unable to hardcode any information about the tables I will be accessing. Thus, I will be using a lot of raw SQL queries within Slick, and then proceeding to filter and paginate through the data using Slick tools.

My question is this:

In the example provided in Slick's documentation:

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

val action = sql"select ID, NAME, AGE from PERSON".as[(Int,String,Int)]
db.run(action)
```

You see that `action` has `.as[(Int, String, Int)]` at the end of it, I'm guessing to tell the compiler what to expect. That makes sense. However, what I'd like to do would require me to know that information based on non-source-code. Is there any way to have the rows returned from the query be some sort of List or Array that I could access with dynamic information (such as index numbers). I'd be willing to accept a `List[String]` for example to make this less of a type headache.

I'll keep working at it, but as a Slick newbie, I was wondering if anyone more experienced than me would have a solution off the top of their head.

Comment: This is a huge no-no in slick as it contradicts the main reason that slick was created - type safety. Can you provide more details as to what your actual problem is? Are you literally executing query based on some externally fetched text file!?

Comment: The arguments to the `sql` interpolator and `as[T]` are static. If your query is dynamic you're probably better off using raw jdbc.

Comment: @DanielShin Haha not quite. I'm attempting to build an application that will read data from a database using column information (type, sizes, etc) provided in a json file. The issue I am trying to solve is that, historically, people have hardcoded this DB information into the application, thus making any change to the DB an entire release cycle from actualization. It also means that in order to add in support for another database, you'd wait an entire release cycle away. I am trying to build a generic database reader that get's it's specs/schema from json files.

Comment: did you ever get this working?